# invoice in openerp

Tags: python, xml, database, odoo

Why does this error occur?

```
 ProgrammingError: operator does not exist: integer = boolean
    LINE 1: select name, model from ir_ui_view where (id=false or inheri...
                                                        ^
    HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). 
    You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to compare an integer with a boolean (as indicated by the error).

Since this is SQL 0 (the number) doesn't equal false (a boolean type).

You need to explicity give it a numeric id or filter on NULL (depending on the schema of the table).

Answer (score 1):

When coding in openerp this error arise when you try to write to a record(database table) with empty list of ids. So check whether you have provided correct ids for the write function